# Getting two spans to display one under the other next to a thumbnail

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to achieve a layout with a thumbnail with two pieces of information underneath each other and then some options floating to the right as shown below:

[image]

I have tried to achieve this with the following markup and CSS:

```css
span.author_name {
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

span.comment_tools {
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #939393;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

span.comment_tools a {
  color: #939393;
  -webkit-transition: color 500ms linear;
  -moz-transition: color 500ms linear;
  -ms-transition: color 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: color 500ms linear;
  transition: color 500ms linear;
}

span.comment_tools a:hover {
  color: #1a7bbf;
}

span.date_time {
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: #939393;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

span.author_name em { vertical-align: top; }
span.date_time em { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

```html
<div class="author_metadata">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7b3c9600bd9d213f52750ac083c1ac28?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" height="32" width="32" />
  <span class="author_name">Thomas Russell <em>says</em>:</span>
  <span class="comment_tools"><a href="#">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Reply</a></span>
  <span class="date_time">14th December 2014 <em>at</em> 1:38 am</span>
</div>
```

However, this results in the `date_time` span being offset slightly. What's the best way to achieve what I'm going for here, bearing in mind this will be a list of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the `.author_name` and `.date_time` in a `div#container`, change `span.author_name` and `span.date_name` to `div.author_name` and `div.date_name` respectivey and finally, apply `display: inline-block` and `vertical-algin: top` to `img` and the `#container`.

You don't need vendor prefixes for [`transition`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) other than `-webkit-`.

```css
div.author_name {
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #333;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
span.comment_tools {
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #939393;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
span.comment_tools a {
  color: #939393;
  -webkit-transition: color 500ms linear;
  transition: color 500ms linear;
}
span.comment_tools a:hover {
  color: #1a7bbf;
}
div.date_time {
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: #939393;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
div.author_name em { vertical-align: top; }
div.date_time em { vertical-align: bottom; }
img, div#left-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="author_metadata">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7b3c9600bd9d213f52750ac083c1ac28?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" height="32" width="32" />
  <div id="left-container">
    <div class="author_name">Thomas Russell <em>says</em>:</div>
    <div class="date_time">14th December 2014 <em>at</em> 1:38 am</div>
  </div>
  <span class="comment_tools"><a href="#">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Reply</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

- Float the image to the left
- Make `.author_name` and `.date_time` block elements
- Place `.comment_tools` earlier
- Add the margin to the image instead of to `.author_name` and `.date_time`

```css
.author_metadata {
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.author_metadata > img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.author_metadata > span {
  display: block;
}
span.author_name {
  color: #333;
}
span.comment_tools {
  color: #939393;
  float: right;
}
span.comment_tools a {
  color: #939393;
  -webkit-transition: color 500ms linear;
  -moz-transition: color 500ms linear;
  -ms-transition: color 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: color 500ms linear;
  transition: color 500ms linear;
}
span.comment_tools a:hover {
  color: #1a7bbf;
}
span.date_time {
  color: #939393;
}
```

```html
<div class="author_metadata">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7b3c9600bd9d213f52750ac083c1ac28?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" height="32" width="32" />
  <span class="comment_tools">
    <a href="#">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Reply</a>
  </span>
  <span class="author_name">Thomas Russell <em>says</em>:</span>
  <span class="date_time">14th December 2014 <em>at</em> 1:38 am</span>
</div>
```